# Using TAGS on widgets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use tags in UI widgets but the tag value is not available in the handler function (returns 'null').

Is it supposed to work like that (in this case it's kind of useless for me) or am I doing something wrong ?  if anyone has any experience with TAGS, I'd appreciate any advice ;-)

Here is the code I used for testing :

```
function doGet(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var lbl = app.createTextBox().setWidth('400').setId('lbl');
  lbl.setText('empty').setTag('tag value');
  lbl.setText('original value = '+lbl.getTag());// this line to check that setTag / getTag is working as it should in the same function
  app.add(panel.add(lbl));
  var CH = app.createServerHandler('showtag').addCallbackElement(panel);
  lbl.addClickHandler(CH)

  return app;
}


function showtag(){
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var lbl = app.getElementById('lbl')
lbl.setText('new value = '+lbl.getTag());
return app
}
```

It can be tested [with this link](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyLpTcu7SuUHfLFAEKwL-6JWQmqJufpymlGlp3ZhkSwVxalkfIR/exec)

*EDIT : I added a line in the code that reads and writes the tag in the doGet function, just to test ...*

**EDIT 2 : the solution by Srik, as simple as that :**

```
function showtag(e){
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var lbl = app.getElementById('lbl')
lbl.setText('from showtag value = '+e.parameter.lbl_tag);
return app
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the tags for the same purpose as you to store intermediate values for server handlers and also without success. I solved this problem by using the [Hidden](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_hidden) class.

Comment: Too bad ;-/ I didn't found any reference to this on the issue tracker, did you ?

Comment: No, I even have not tried to find. Probably it is a feature and not a bug.

Comment: I wonder how such a 'feature' can be useful if its value is not visible nor recordable... ;-)  I'm curious to see if someone has some other point of view... thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I think, the Tags (setTag) is something similar to Ids (setId). I.e. both of these parameters is possible to set during creation and impossible to change in a server handler. A possible use case of Tags is to combine controls by some criterion with different Id.

Comment: hmmm, setTag() can be used in the server function and a following getTag() gets its value but the problem is that it has to be in the scope of the function... to me it looks more like a bug than a feature

Comment: Agree. Submit a bug to the issue tracker.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=741 was closed 'invalid' so the workaround still applies . Great, you can setTag in the handler but cannot getTag  some feature :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. There is a small quirk here. IN your handler, you can access the tag value in the following method

```
function doGet(){
   ....
   var lbl = app.createTextBox().setWidth('400').setId('lbl');
   lbl.setText('empty').setTag('tag value');
   ....
}

function showtag(e){
  var tag = e.parameter.lbl_tag; /* I'm not sure if it us Tag or tag */
  ....
}
```

Comment: waow !? that's nice ! I didn't know that ... thanks a lot, this is definitely the place to meet people 'who know' things' ;-)  now I'll have to recover the code I throw away... revision history will be helpful ;-)