# getTag() method not properly working for google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

What i am doing in writing a script that lets the User interact with a data table. Every series that the user chooses creates a button, and then plots the series on a graph. if the user click the button it rooms the series. All there the data is stored in a hidden JSON string. the columns, or series that the user whats to see are stored in an array that i call index, it is also a hidden JSON string) Each button is connected to its own client handler, which has a

```
.forTargets(the index i was talking about).setTag(to the corresponding column in the data array)
```

and they are all connected to the same server handler. So when the button is clicked the client handler sets the tag for the index to the series that it is supposed to be removed. Now the server handler will run it get the index by ID and get the Tag. This is were it goes wrong. The tag is always null.

The first thing i tried was to see if my client handler was not working properly. So i set the tag of the index to some number, but the getTag method in the Server handler still returned null.

idk, but maybe Tags are not saved in the UI instance??

Below is the first bit of the Server handler.

```
function clickServer(e) {
   e = e.parameter;
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

   var master = JSON.parse(e.dataTable, "reviver");
   var index = JSON.parse(e.index, "reviver"); 

   var hidden = app.getElementById("hiddenIndex");
   var tag = hidden.getTag();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue you are meeting is more related to timing : handlers are called simultaneously, this is true for client an server handlers as well, that means that if the client handler changes a hidden tag value this change happens too late for the server handler function to 'see' it. What you should do is create a separate button to trigger the server handler that the user would use after all the other parameters where set.
This very same method is used in the known workaround used to get [radioButtons value](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/some-ui-elements#TOC-Playing-with-RadioButtons)

Also, why do you use tags on the hidden widget ? you could use it with direct access by `setValue()` and `e.parameter.hiddenName` since they are already invisible by nature... ?

Note also that you can set a value in client handlers as long a these values are defined inside the Ui instance (the do Get function) either by constant variables or by another client Handler in the same function, as shown in the before mentioned example with radioButtons... but that's only a detail.
In this context if you need to get a widget value (inside the doGet function) you should of course use `getValue()` to get the widget value as no `e.parameter` is available at this time.

I hope I've been clear enough, re-reading this I'm not very sure but.... just ask if something is missing ;-)

Comment: Serge, thank you very much for pointing my fault. To avoid confusion, I am deleting my comment about limited possibilities of the client handlers.

Comment: No prob ;-) I modified my answer accordingly... It didn't make sense to refer to something that is not there anymore did it ?

Answer (score 1):

The tags values are passed to handlers via parameters. In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829479/using-tags-on-widgets) this fact is explained in details.

Comment: So the way i want to do this want work. Do you have any suggestions to how I can approach this?

Comment: Hm.. should be `var tag = e.parameter.hiddenIndex_tag;`

Comment: Sorry, I should have added some info. Because, like Id's, tags cannot change, so my client handler does not do what it is supposed to do. What i need to do is find a way for a client handler to change some sort of something so that i can then reference it in the server handler